# Python: find sections from a text file using backward loop

Tags: python, for-loop, text, filter, package

In python, I have a input text file (**as below**), which includes 3 sections of text, and I need to first find all the lines in the bottom of each section of the text that includes **'shsux/en'** , and then under this section, I would like to loop back and search for all the lines that start with **'udp' and 'jkp'**, and output the whole section into a new text file.

```
hsussksdjeoslllllllllllll/shsux/ujkes
        jkp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
        jkp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhsesssssssssssssssss
        jkp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhsesssssssssssssssss
hsussksdjeoslllllllllllll/shsux/en
------------------------------------------------------------
hsussksdjeoslllllllllllll/shsux/sed
        udp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
        udp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhsesssssssssssssssss
        jkp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhsesssssssssssssssss
hsussksdjeoslllllllllllll/shsux/en
------------------------------------------------------------
hsussksdjeoslllllllllllll/dfsux/df
        udp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
        udp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhsesssssssssssssssss
        jkp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhsesssssssssssssssss
hsussksdjeoslllllllllllll/dfsux/en
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So for example, the first line with '/shsux/en' is

```
hsussksdjeoslllllllllllll/shsux/en
```

I need to find this first, and once I have this, I wonder how I can back loop for section

```
        jkp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
        jkp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhsesssssssssssssssss
        jkp_shsu_hhhhhhhhhsesssssssssssssssss
```

and return lines with 'jkp'

Any suggestion for the functions that I should use, and how I can approach this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is impossible to list all lines from section that match some condition, if you can't specify how bloc section (and you have multiple different sections in one file).
But, assuming that you only know how section ends you can loop twice over your input file. In first iteration you can store numbers of lines, where you find "end of section" string. Something like:

```
end_of_section_line_nb = []

for counter, line in enumerate(file):
    if #condition to check, use regex or just "some_string in line", depending on your needs
    end_of_section_line_nb.append(counter)
```

Then loop over file again and search for each occurrence of string ("udp"...) in any block. After first iteration you have numbers of lines were section ends, so you can check in which section you are.

In this way you will assign "udp" stuff to next following recognized block, but you won't be able tell if it's in it (since you did not specify how block starts).

You could also loop over file once and always store in memory some number of preceding lines, but it would be inefficient if your sections are big.